# C++ Base64 of Sha1 - WebSocket Handshake

Tags: c++, binary, hex, websocket, handshake

i am currently trying to get a C++ Server running which can communicate with a WebSocket. The HandShake consists of a couple of steps and I have no success with the last one.

The first Step is to generate a SHA1 encoded string and I successfully obtained the right hex string. (Example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket & https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455).

My output is in both cases the same as stated in the documentation:

```
Wikipedia: 1d 29 ab 73 4b 0c 95 85 24 00 69 a6 e4 e3 e9 1b 61 da 19 69
My Server: 1d 29 ab 73 4b 0c 95 85 24 00 69 a6 e4 e3 e9 1b 61 da 19 69

IETF Docu: b3 7a 4f 2c c0 62 4f 16 90 f6 46 06 cf 38 59 45 b2 be c4 ea
My Server: b3 7a 4f 2c c0 62 4f 16 90 f6 46 06 cf 38 59 45 b2 be c4 ea
```

So this is right. When i now do the Base64 encoding i come to the following results:

```
Wikipedia: HSmrc0sMlYUkAGmm5OPpG2HaGWk=
My Server: MWQyOWFiNzM0YjBjOTU4NTI0MDA2OWE2ZTRlM2U5MWI2MWRhMTk2OQ==

IETF Docu: s3pPLMBiTxaQ9kYGzzhZRbK+xOo=
My Server: YjM3YTRmMmNjMDYyNGYxNjkwZjY0NjA2Y2YzODU5NDViMmJlYzRlYQ==
```

And this a completely different. I confirmed that my Base64 algorithm works wtih certain online converters and they all produced the output my server did. So the problem is the input format. I found a forum entry in a javascript forum where one had the same problem and the answer was that , instead of passing the 40 character hex string, we should pass the 20 character binary representation.

I know that openssl SHA1 returns a binary representation but i can't use the library for certain reasons. The SHA1 library i use, puts the encoded output in an int array. The output looks like this (IETF example):

```
result[0] = 3011137324
result[1] = 3227668246
result[2] = 2432058886
result[3] = 3476576581
result[4] = 2998846698
```

I convert this than to hex like this:

```
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << std::setfill('0');
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
                    oss << std::setw(8) << std::hex << result[i];
            }
```

Now the big question. How can i convert my hex string to binary?

Thanks a lot in advance .
Markus

**EDIT**

If someone is interested in the code:
https://github.com/MarkusPfundstein/C---Websocket-Server

Answer (score 2):

I was testing websocket in c and found that bytes were in the wrong order. Adapting the order (in reverse) solved my problem with base64 encoding, resulting in correct accepted key string:

```
unsigned char byteResult [20];
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        byteResult[(i * 4) + 3] = sha.result[i] & 0x000000ff;
        byteResult[(i * 4) + 2] = (sha.result[i] & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
        byteResult[(i * 4) + 1] = (sha.result[i] & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
        byteResult[(i * 4) + 0] = (sha.result[i] & 0xff000000) >> 24;
    }
```

Comment: thanks. here you can see how i fixed it (method Connection::Authenticate() https://github.com/MarkusPfundstein/C---Websocket-Server/blob/master/Network/Connection.cc

Answer (score 1):

Most Baser64 encoder expect a byte array/stream of binary data. You want to split up your ints into bytes, using bit masks and logic shifts. On 32 bit systems each int contains 4 bytes, you can extract them as follows:

```
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

    byteResult[(i * 4) + 0] = result[i] & 0x000000ff;
    byteResult[(i * 4) + 1] = (result[i] & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
    byteResult[(i * 4) + 2] = (result[i] & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
    byteResult[(i * 4) + 3] = (result[i] & 0xff000000) >> 24;
}
```

Where `byteResult` is a byte[] 4 times larger than the result array. I'm assuming the order the bytes have been packed into the ints here, it may be the other way round.

Pass this byte[] into your Base64 encoder.

Comment: awesome i will try it out asap

Comment: I am very sorry but it doesnt work :( result is an array of 5 , so dont i have to enumerator until i < 5 ? It also produces very weird output.

Comment: sorry you're quite right, should be 5 - answer updated. Also see my note regarding byte ordering. In what way is the output weird?

Comment: thats byteresult: ,Oz�Ob�F��EY8��ľ�b37a4f2cc0624f1690f64606cf385945b2bec4ea

Comment: ok - the bytes should look weird, they are the SHA1 hash of the input - its raw binary data, not text. Does the Base64 encoded version of those bytes does not match what you're looking for?

Comment: What input does your Base64 encoder take? Do you pass it the byte[] directly?

Comment: hey friend, you i did pass it directly. I did use openssl in the end to solve the problem but thanks a lot for your effort.

Answer (score 1):

On a slightly related note (I see you already discovered the [EVP BIO base64 way](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/BIO_f_base64.html)...):

```
result[0] = 3011137324
...
oss << std::setw(8) << std::hex << result[i];
```

If I understand correctly this results in output `b37a4f2c`, which is your IETF Docu example. Be very careful here, because you are threading on the open water dangers of platform specific [endianess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). 0n3011137324 is indeed 0xb37a4f2c but *only on little endian machines*, like Intel architectures. You would probably be better off to reinterpret cast the `&result[0]` to `unsigned char*` and then handle that as an array of bytes, instead of an array of (unsigned) ints.